# Find lines with numbers

Tags: regex, bash

This code why can't find the lines in the file what's contain number?

```
head $1 | grep '^[.]*[0-9]{1,}[.]*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.`, when used in a character group like `[.]`, means the literal dot.

Furthermore it doesn't matter what's in front or behind the number when you just look for *lines with numbers*.

You want:

```
head "$1" | grep '[0-9]'
```

or

```
head "$1" | grep '[[:digit:]]'
```

You may want to read: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html

Comment: Thanks! And how can I add to find only the lines what contain 4 or more numbers?
```
grep '[0-9]{4,}'
```
is not working for me.

Comment: try: `grep -E '[0-9]{4}' file_name`

Comment: @vmarci21 yeah, or `grep '[0-9]\{4,\}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all lines in the file "$1" that contain at least on digit you can just use

```
 grep '[0-9]' "$1"
```

'head' only gives the first 10 lines of the file. Just using grep without pipe '|' scans the whole file.

(BTW: put $1 into double-quotes to be sure that the file name is handled properly if it contains some special character like spaces.)